Why can't the weak monadic second order theory of $\omega$ successors descibe prefix
Doner's "Tree Acceptors and Some of Their Applications" (1970) casually mentions that in the weak monadic second order theory of omega successors (WS$\omega$S), i.e. the theory of:

Finite sequences of natural numbers
Finite sets of sequences of natural numbers
$S_i$ operations for each $i$ which tack an $i$ onto the end of a sequence
$\in$ between types

one cannot express the predicate $\phi(x,y) :\equiv \exists n: y = S_n(x)$. This is very intuitive, but the text doesn't provide a proof. I would appreciate some help formalizing this proof.
Of course if we had a formula expressing $\phi$, it could only make use of $S_1, \ldots, S_n$ for some finite $n$. One can then pick an $m > n$ and mess around with $S_m$ somehow?
Alternately, I considered using a compactness argument: Let $T$ be the set of all true formulas in WS$\omega$S, add in constants $c$ and $d$, then every finite subset of $T \cup \{\phi(c,d)\} \cup \{d \neq S_n(c)\}_n$ is satisfiable, so the whole collection is consistent. But how do we know the whole collection is satisfiable in the standard model of WS$\omega$S and not just in some nonstandard models?
